# Loading images from server

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working on a news app (IOS), where I try to load data from server. Loading text data works fine, but when trying to load images it starts to misbehave.
Here is my code to load images:

This method creates an image based on the data:

```
func processImageData(data: Data?, error: Error?)-> ImageResult {
    guard
    let imageData = data,
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
            if data == nil {
                print("The image URL is empty")
                return .Failure(error!)
            }
            else {
                print("Something went wrong when creating an image")
                return .Failure(ImageError.ImageCreationError)
            }
    }
    return .Success(image)
}
```

Then this method is used in another method:

```
func getArticleImage(article: Article) {

    let urlString = article.imageUrl
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    { (data, response, error) in

        let result = self.processImageData(data: data, error: error)
        if case let .Success(image) = result {
            article.articleImage = image
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

In the TableViewController class I have a method that retrieves an array of article objects, within this method I call the second method from above (getArticleImage) to retrieve an image for each article separately, this is done in more primitive way, so that the images are downloaded even for news articles that are not displayed yet in the table's visible area. This is done for the testing purpose

```
 func loadNewsFeed() {
    articleStore.getNewsFeed() {
        (newsResult) in

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            switch newsResult {
            case let .Success(news):
                self.articles = news
                print("Successfully found: \(news.count) news articles")
                // Retrieve image for each news article
                for article in news {
                    self.articleStore.getArticleImage(article: article)
                }

            case let .Failure(error):
                self.articles.removeAll()
                print("Error retrieving news: \(error)")
            }
            // Stop Loading Anmation
            self.removeLoadingScreen()

            // Reload data to display latest news
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

}
```

However, no images are displayed. I have used some print statements in the methods to see where is the error and the method prints the first print statement from the first method of the three that I wrote above:

```
func processImageData(data: Data?, error: Error?)-> ImageResult {
   ....
   if data == nil {
       print("The image URL is empty")
       return .Failure(error!)
   }
   ....
}
```

Hence, it appears that the data that is created from article's image URL is empty which is strange, considering the fact that each article has working image URL. So I would assume that the problem is in the first method, even though I am not sure what is exactly wrong with it.

Comment: `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)` does not create a URL for an external server. What happens if you change the line to `let url = URL(string: urlString)!`?

Comment: Dammit, how could I miss that, yes it finally works, thank you vary much